# Coloring a map of India

Tags: image-processing, visualization, geography

Below is a map of India (`img`).

[image]

and I can visualize it in the following way:

```
imgbin = Binarize@img;
MorphologicalComponents[imgbin] // Colorize
```

and the result is:

[image]

#### Edit

Following a manual approach, I can isolate the small components:

```
sc = SelectComponents[imgbin, #Count < 60 &];
```

However, this gives me

[image]

Now I find the coordinates of the centroids:

```
centroids = ComponentMeasurements[sc, "Centroid"];
```

This gives me

> ```
> {1 -> {523.425, 182.274}, 2 -> {545.125, 182.563}, 3 -> {521.089, 154.518}, 
>  4 -> {96.2778, 154.722}, 5 -> {101.5, 150.625}, 6 -> {285.375, 146.667}, 
>  7 -> {111.7, 136.}, 8 -> {517.868, 133.947}, 9 -> {91.8846, 134.885}, 
>  10 -> {99.3889, 135.167}, 11 -> {95.0882, 122.382}, 12 -> {531.136, 105.409}, 
>  13 -> {535.5, 94.}, 14 -> {541.4, 92.6}, 15 -> {551.833, 93.8333}, 
>  16 -> {540.333, 86.5833}, 17 -> {564., 63.5}, 18 -> {557.929, 61.5}, 
>  19 -> {558.833, 55.8333}, 20 -> {567.5, 27.}, 21 -> {575.689, 20.3491}}
> ```

From this information, I think, the grouping can be done. I need to choose two thresholds for the `X` coordinates of the centroids. Manually, I can set the thresholds as `100` and `200`. Then, the components having centroids with `x < 100` will be grouped into one, the component having the centroid with `100 < x < 200` will be grouped into another one (this component should be discarded as it is already considered as a component earlier) and finally the components having centroids with `x > 200` will be grouped into the second one.

---

However, I wish to group some of the components as shown below:

[image]

That is, the components inside the circle at the bottom left should be grouped into a single component and visualized with a single color and the components inside the ellipse at the bottom right should be grouped into another single component and visualized with another unique color while keeping the rest of the map unchanged.

How can I do so?

**Edit 2:** I can now group the components desired in a very manual way as follows:

```
scleft = SelectComponents[
  imgbin, #Count < 80 && #Centroid[[1]] < 130 &];
scright = 
 SelectComponents[imgbin, #Count < 80 && #Centroid[[1]] > 350 &];
```

and the components for the rest of the parts

```
mc = MorphologicalComponents[
  ImageSubtract[imgbin, ImageAdd[scleft, scright]]];
```

Now how can I join these components - `scleft`, `scright` and `mc` and get the desired result?

**Edit 3:** Both the answers by `@kglr` and `@Chip` Hurst are acceptable to me. However, I don't like the way they have colorized `scleft` and `scright`. I would prefer to append these two components into `mc` so that I can have all the components together and then visualize using simply `Colorize`.

Comment: What have you tried so far ? Understand your original attempts will help us get started in helping you.

Comment: @user6014 I am not sure. Maybe group them by the components' centroid coordinates.

Comment: If you post code examples of your best attempt so far it will be a good starting point for someone to build off of and hopefully get you to the next step.

Comment: @user6014 see my edit.

Comment: Majis, may i suggest you re-visit your previous questions and check if any of the answers is worth accepting?

Comment: @kglr I check the answers time to time. Since you are specifically asking this, I will check again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A manual way (since OP has suggested that this question is not about clustering, more about how to deal with groups of labels) to do this would be to right click on the image, then get indices. Select the upper left corner and the bottom right corner of the bounding box of a group of components and then use ctrl+c to copy the indices. Paste it into the notebook. Do this for both groups. Then rearrange the indices for use in `Part`, in the following way:

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/6wQT9.jpg"];
comps = MorphologicalComponents[Binarize[img]];
comps[[492 ;; 549, 76 ;; 125]] = comps[[492 ;; 549, 76 ;; 125]] /. Except[0, _Integer] -> 1000;
comps[[459 ;; 648, 498 ;; 593]] = comps[[459 ;; 648, 498 ;; 593]] /. Except[0, _Integer] -> 1001;
comps = ArrayComponents[comps];
Colorize[comps]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This code works also without `ArrayComponents`. What `ArrayComponents` does is that it reindexes the components so that they are consecutive integers rather than the `1000` and `1001` that we arbitrarily used in the code.

```
comps // Flatten // DeleteDuplicates
```

> `{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, \
>   19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27}`

If I were to finish what OP started, I'd do it similarly:

```
binimg = Binarize[img];
scleft = SelectComponents[binimg, #Count < 80 && #Centroid[[1]] < 130 &];
scright = SelectComponents[binimg, #Count < 80 && #Centroid[[1]] > 350 &];
mc = MorphologicalComponents[ImageSubtract[binimg, ImageAdd[scleft, scright]]];
mc += 1000 ImageData[scleft];
mc += 1001 ImageData[scright];
Colorize[
 mc,
 ColorRules -> Join[
   Table[i -> Green, {i, 25}], {
    1000 -> Blue,
    1001 -> Red
    }]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: This is also a very good approach. However, I am having a problem with all the three answers. I don't want to colorize the map with the default color scheme. I have my own set of colors and I want to render the map with my colors. However, `ColorFunction` is not an option for `Image`. Is it possible to do so in any other way?

Comment: @CE Secondly, I don't understand what are the purposes of using the values `1000` and `1001`. Can you please explain this to me?

Comment: @Majis The colors should be specified as an option to `Colorize`, not `Image`. `Colorize` accepts both `ColorRules` and `ColorFunction`. Those are arbitrary labels. We have to give them some labels, right? So we can give them the labels 235 and 367, or 10323023 and 29301490. It doesn't matter which, but they must be unique. For this particular image, since we have 25 other components, the label number must be larger than 25.

Comment: @CE This means I can use `ColorRules` or `ColorFunction` with `Colorize`. Yes, I understand that they are just labels. Then how can I use it to apply custom colors?

Comment: @Majis I updated the last example to demonstrate this. Is it more understandable now?

Comment: Yes. Now I understand it. Let me check it thoroughly.

Answer (score 8):

Another idea is to dilate the image slightly to find 'connected' components.

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/6wQT9.jpg"];

mask = Binarize[Dilation[img, DiskMatrix[15]]];
comps = MorphologicalComponents[mask];

{chain2, chain1, mainland} = SortBy[Table[
  Binarize[img*Image[1 - Unitize[comps - i]]], {i, 3}], Total];

Colorize[MorphologicalComponents[mainland, CornerNeighbors -> False]] + 
  ImageMultiply[chain1, Green] + 
  ImageMultiply[chain2, Red]
```

[image]

---

#### Edit

To color the island chains from within `Colorize`:

```
mcomp = MorphologicalComponents[mainland, CornerNeighbors -> False];
max = Max[mcomp];

Colorize[mcomp + (max + 1)ImageData[chain1] + (max + 2)ImageData[chain2]]
```

[image]

Comment: It's not what I need. `mc` is a list of components while, `scleft` and `scright` are images. I want to convert `scleft` and `scright` into components and append them to `mc` and then apply `Colorize[mc]`.

Comment: @Majis see my edit.

Comment: Yes, Now this is very straightforward. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 7):

**Update 2:** ***have all the components together and then visualize using simply Colorize***:

Modify the `MorphologicalComponents` matrix to assign the same label to members of a cluster:

```
replace = Thread[Alternatives @@ # -> First[#]] & /@ clusters;
MorphologicalComponents[imgbin] /. replace // Colorize
```

[image]

**Update:**

```
clusters = FindClusters[#[[2, 1]] -> # & /@ 
  ComponentMeasurements[MorphologicalComponents[imgbin], 
    {"Centroid", "Count"}, #2 < 80 && (#[[1]] < 130 || #[[1]] > 350) &], 2][[All, All, 1]];

Colorize[MorphologicalComponents[imgbin], 
 ColorRules -> Join @@ (Thread /@ Thread[clusters -> {Red, Green}])]
```

[image]

**Original answer:**

```
clusters = FindClusters[#[[2, 1]] -> # & /@ 
   ComponentMeasurements[imgbin, {"Centroid", "Count"}, #2 < 65 &], 2][[All, All, 1]];
Colorize[MorphologicalComponents[imgbin], 
 ColorRules -> Join @@ (Thread /@ Thread[clusters -> {Red, Green}])]
```

[image]

**Note**: Need further refinement to exclude the red elements on the continent.

Comment: see my edit to the question.

Comment: @Majis, please see the update.

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I need. However, I am having a small problem. Do you really get the regions at the bottom right of the same color? When I run your code, I get the top 4 elements yellow.

Comment: Don't worry, `(#[[1]] < 130 || #[[1]] > 250)` gives me the desired result. Thanks a lot.