# Coloring a binary mask image

Tags: performance-tuning, image-processing, color

My answer to [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/183689/coloring-a-map-of-india) question involved changing the white in a binary mask to a different color.

I came up with a few ways to do this:

```
colorizeMask1[im_, color_] := ColorReplace[im, 1 -> color]

colorizeMask2[im_, color_] := Colorize[im, {ColorRules -> {0 -> Black, 1 -> color}}]

colorizeMask3[im_, color_] := ReplacePixelValue[im, PixelValuePositions[im, 1] -> color]

colorizeMask4[im_, color_] := ColorCombine[(List @@ color) * im]

colorizeMask5[im_, color_] := ImageMultiply[im, ConstantImage[color, ImageDimensions[im]]]
```

I'm not quite satisfied with any of these: they are either slow or seem too round-about.

```
im = Binarize[RegionImage[Annulus[], RasterSize -> 1024]];
colorizeMask4[im, Green]
```

[image]

```
First[AbsoluteTiming[#[im, Green];]] & /@ 
  {colorizeMask1, colorizeMask2, colorizeMask3, colorizeMask4, colorizeMask5}
```

> ```
> {0.252601, 2.45989, 0.084044, 0.011478, 0.035167}
> ```

Is there a faster, built in way to do this?

Comment: 0.01s seems pretty quick to me, what is your time goal? `Colorize` would be my go-to but I accept that 2.5s is too slow!

Comment: @CarlLange perhaps my question is not well enough defined. My fast solutions seemed roundabout and less obvious to attempt. The obvious looking solutions are slow. I thought perhaps I was overlooking something.

Comment: Can't test right now, but I remember doing this by taking the `Outer[]` product of the binary image's `ImageData[]` with the RGB triplet of the new color (treated as a vector).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
ImageMultiply[im, Green] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image]

versus `0.031786` for `colorizeMask4` (fastest of the five in OP).

Comment: Thank you. I had tried `im * Green` thinking `*` would be equivalent to `ImageMultiply` in this case!

Comment: @ChipHurst, my pleasure. Thank you for the accept.

Comment: Also note that this is a 'Basic Example' in the ImageMultiply docs!

Comment: @Chip, although I almost  always use this form, somehow today it was the last one I tried:)

Comment: It also works with `ImageSubtract`: `ImageSubtract[im, RGBColor[1, 0, 1]]`

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively, ColorCombine the mask with an all-black image:

```
im = Binarize[RegionImage[Annulus[], RasterSize -> 1024]];
black = ImageMultiply[im, 0];
ColorCombine[{black, im, black}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

this takes 0.001806 vs 0.019607 for colorizeMask4